# What is the definition for different access attributes in object access auditing?

Tags: windows, access-control, logging

Though there is documentation available about configuring Object Access auditing, there is no place where I have found any documents explaining the different attributes in Object Access Auditing. Can someone explain or show some reference for the different access attributes in Object Access, please?

[image]

[image]

Also, in the logs, event ID 4663 the Accesses fields gives more different values.

[image]

Comment: Do you want us to write for you what each attribute means?

Comment: Yes, that would help. If you have some reference link, then that would be sufficient too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All attributes can be seen here under "Permissions for files and folders" on Microsoft technet documentation:

[Permissions for files and folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787794(v=ws.10).aspx)

The only attribute that is not there is the `Full control` which upon selecting will check all the rest of the attributes which is the detention of full control.

> Also, in the logs, event ID 4663 the Accesses fields gives more different values.

These are the names of the attributes in the registry.